# Sum multiple column with match criteria in row data vba

Tags: vba

I wanna ask related to excel vba.

I'm trying to consolidate data from worksheet, containing data like screenshot(1).

[image]

What i'm want to do is to consolidate data with unique row is in row H (CTP.GRP) and sum column M(Nominal) populate to another sheet in column utlization & column P(Mtm in IDR) Popullate data to another sheet column market value

My code only sum one column, anyone can help with code how to sum two column?

[image]

```
Sub ins_data()

Dim x As Variant

Dim y As Variant

Dim countDict As Variant

Dim a As Long

 

Set countDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

 

x = Sheets("Data").Range("A2").CurrentRegion

 

ReDim y(1 To UBound(x, 1), 1 To UBound(x, 2))

For a = 2 To UBound(x, 1)

cat1 = x(a, 8)

val1 = x(a, 16)

If countDict.exists(cat1) Then

countDict(cat1) = countDict(cat1) + val1

Else

countDict(cat1) = val1

End If

Next a

 

i = 1

For Each d In countDict

y(i, 2) = d

y(i, 8) = countDict(d)

i = i + 1

Next d

 

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X").Range("B5").Resize(UBound(y), UBound(y, 2)).Value = y
```

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited after OP’s further clarification

you could use this code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ins_data()
    Dim countDict As Object, countDict2 As Object
    Set countDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set countDict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim x() As Variant
    x = Sheets("Data").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Value2

    Dim a As Long
    For a = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
        countDict(x(a, 8)) = countDict(x(a, 8)) + x(a, 13)
        countDict2(x(a, 8)) = countDict(x(a, 8)) + x(a, 16)
    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("X").Range("B5").Resize(countDict.Count) ‘ change “B5” to the actual worksheet “X” cell you want to start writing Sheets("Data")) column H unique values from
        .Value = Application.Transpose(countDict.Keys)
        .Offset(, 6).Value = Application.Transpose(countDict.Items) ‘ change “6” to your actual column offset from Sheets("X") referenced column (currently, “B”) you want to start writing Sheets("Data")) column M consolidated sum from
        .Offset(, 7).Value = Application.Transpose(countDict2.Items) ‘ change “7” to your actual column offset from Sheets("X") referenced column (currently, “B”) you want to start writing Sheets("Data")) column P consolidated sum from
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi DisplayName, thank you for ur reply. I mean: sum column M populate in another sheet in column utlization. Sum column P populate in another sheet column market value. I need speed tovmy macro, because i run alot of macro code to consolidate data from my worksheets.

Comment: @Syukry, see edited answer, where you may want to change output sheet column reference (currently, B, H and I) to suit your needs. If this answers your question then you may consider marking it as accepted. Thank you

Comment: Hi DisplayName, thank you verymuch. It work.thumbsup